# When will this MySQL table become slow

Tags: mysql, performance

Table shown below is:

1. searched only [simple select], no deleting/inserting/joining with others etc.
2. columns are set / no changes here
3. 99%+ of the time searches will go by same column, which is indexed (column: "key" in example)
4. engine: MyISAM
5. row format: dynamic
6. there are 2 other indexes (columns: id/location)

Since this table will be used with every page load, I'm concerned with size vs. speed ratio. Up to how many rows (roughly) will it be very fast, then fast, then slow, then reduced to crawl?

```
[columns name]   |  [data type]       |   [collation]
id               |   int(11)            
name             |   varchar(64)      |   utf8_general_ci       
key              |   varchar(64)      |   utf8_general_ci    |   [ 99% used for search:  is indexed]    
value            |   text             |   utf8_general_ci       
identifier_id    |   int(11)            
sort_order       |   int(5)             
last_adjusted    |   datetime           
location         |   varchar(255)     |   utf8_general_ci       
group_no         |   int(3)
```

Comment: post the results of show indexes from <your table> also a typical query with explain plan.

Comment: Tables aren't "slow". Queries might be.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's what I meant - access to data in table depending on table size - a shortcut, but you have a point - sounds kinda silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very much depends on your server setup.

The amount of memory available to the MySQL server being the main concern, then the type of storage the table is configured for.

You do not specify what type of indexes are in use, is `key` a `UNIQUE` index, or something with duplicates?  I would guess at `UNIQUE`, given the usage - this would remain fast for a very considerable time period.  If you keep in mind that the efficiency is approximately o(log n) for searching a unique index, and that the search itself on such an index is relatively trivial, then the index would have to be out of main memory and on some pretty slow media to make much of a difference.

Comment: I have no access to MySQL memory allowance at the moment, but it is on localhost powered by VDS 1024/50. Also correction: searches go by 2 columns (2nd: identifier_id), bot indexes are not unique. QUESTION: is 20.000 rows still a safe limit? (ball park is what I look for as I will test it when poject is done)

Comment: @Jeffz: Do you mean two columns at once, neither unique - or two columns in different searches? 20,000 records with that table size would result in a fairly small index, even on those text fields, only a few MB.  That would be no problem for most servers.

Comment: thank you for time you are taking -> two columns at once, neither unique is the case - i need this table to be "snappy" - so I also consider splitting content into separate tables - with identifier_id as a separation point. In such case only key would be searched for and each table would never go over 5K rows. But such a split is a hassle. That's the reason for this question.

Comment: @Jeffz: When you are searching, is the WHERE clause both fields with an equality check and an `AND` (`key = 'abc' AND identifier_id = 123`) or are you using an inequality on either index, or combining them with `OR`? (`key = 'abc' OR identifier_id < 50`).  If you are doing the former, then make a combined index on both fields, otherwise have separate indexes on each field.  Leaving it as a single table would most likely be faster. 20K rows is not a lot surprisingly, many millions of rows is not unusual.

Comment: Thank you. It gave me some new perspective and things to test against. Thanks again for your time.